# im4java can't find GhostScript Library when converting images on Web App

Tags: java, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, im4java

I've recently began to use im4java, a java wrapper for ImageMagick, to convert .eps files to .jpg. My code currently is:

```
public void convertESPtoJPG()
{

    //Env.programPAth:  C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16
    //Env.copyToDest: C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16\\NakedWines\\Raw\\
    //Env.convToDest: C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16\\NakedWines\\Converted\\
    log.info("============= Converting Images =============");

    IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
    log.debug("Program path: " + Env.programPath);
    ProcessStarter.setGlobalSearchPath(Env.programPath);

    op.addImage();
    op.addImage();

    ConvertCmd cmd = new ConvertCmd();

    ExtensionFilter filter = new ExtensionFilter("eps");
    FilenameLoader  loader = new FilenameLoader(filter);

    log.debug("Where we are grabbing the raw files from: " + Env.copyToDest);

    List<String> files = loader.loadFilenames(Env.copyToDest);

    log.debug("Size of file list: " + files.size());

    FilenamePatternResolver resolver = new FilenamePatternResolver("%P/%f.jpg");

    for (String img: files)
    {
        try {
            log.debug("Eps: " + img + " jpg: " + Env.convToDest + 
img.substring(img.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, img.length() - 3));

                cmd.run(op,img,resolver.createName(Env.convToDest + 
img.substring(img.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, img.length() - 3)));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        log.info("============= Conversion Complete! =============");
    }
```

For whatever reason when I go into my for loop to call cmd.run(...), I get the following error:

```
convert.exe: Postscript delegate failed `[ghostscript library] -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -
dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -
dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72" -g612x792 -dEPSCrop  "-
sOutputFile=C:/Users/gregh/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-29780b1FUQNgxDjI1%d" "-
fC:/Users/gregh/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-29780D9DHdD0Pxg_2" "-
fC:/Users/gregh/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-29780uSl3BAqcvWdD"': Error: /undefined in Unexpected
```

I've searched high and low for what might be causing this, but have no clue. Any possible ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at http://forums.famillecollet.com/viewtopic.php?id=2898, it seems that a possible bug exists in the most recent binary release of ImageMagick. I downgraded to ImageMagick 6.8.9.0 and the error went away.